# How can i add insertion point between inner blocks in my custom block like core blocks

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

In `core/buttons` and `core/columns`, you will see an insertion point button between the inner blocks, as shown in the screenshot below. Now I'm building a custom block with inner blocks, how can i enable this feature for my block? Does it out of box?

[image]